Js - Link target button option (blank vs self) in Quill Editor link
Is there any way to add an option button to set a link in quill editor (https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar) as target blank vs self?
By default its setting a link as blank:
<div class="ql-tooltip ql-editing" style="left: -42.225px; top: 268.3px;" data-mode="link">
    <a class="ql-preview" target="_blank" href="about:blank"></a>
    <input type="text" data-formula="e=mc^2" data-link="https://quilljs.com" data-video="Embed URL" class="form-control" placeholder="https://quilljs.com">
    <a class="ql-action"></a>
    <a class="ql-remove"></a>
</div>

I'm using quill as editor option in datatables editor: https://editor.datatables.net/plug-ins/field-type/editor.quill
{
    label: "Bodytext:",
    name: "news.bodytext",
    className: 'block full',
    type: "quill",
    toolbarHtml:
        '<div id="toolbar-toolbar" class="toolbar">'+
            '<span class="ql-formats">'+
                '<button class="ql-bold"></button>'+
            '</span>'+
            '<span class="ql-formats">'+
                '<button class="ql-link"></button>'+
            '</span>'+
        '</div>',
    opts: {
        placeholder: 'Plese enter bodytext here ...'
    }
}

